# Android CTS failed

Tags: android, cts

1.I need to test Android CTS on my Target board.we had downloaded CTS test cases and media filesfrom(https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/downloads.html) CTS files downloaded are: 
A. Android 9.0 R8 Compatibility Test Suite (CTS) - ARM 
B. CTS Media (latest version)

i executed the following command to go to cts prompt:

-> ./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed

-> list devices(detect the devise)

-> run cts --plan CTS

Error details: [CTS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd53Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

CalenderTests module not present in CTS module list. That is the reason NO test executed.

run following commands to get the exact module name.

-> ./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed

-> list modules(detect the devise)

Retrive exact module name from the out of above command and run the respective module using following command.

-> run cts -m

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `CtsCalenderTestCases`

Your full command will be:

```
run cts -m CtsCalenderTestCases -s <Device_ID> -d -o
```